# C# HiddenField value not passing

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, hiddenfield

I am setting my hidden field value using jquery like this

```
select: function (event, ui) {
    $("#<%=hfPatientId.ClientID %>").val(ui.item.val);
}
```

and i want to store this value in one of my property. in my code behind i did it like this.
[image: Null on left side]
[image: Values on right side]

```
objTicketBO.Patient_Id = hfPatientId.Value.ToString();
```

now my problem is my selected value is binding in right side of = but it is not binding on left side. i.e on hovering over .Value i am getting the value. but on running this code it is throwing error NullValueValidation.

Comment: you are assigning a string(`hfPatientId.Value.ToString()`) to integer(`objTicketBO.Patient_Id`)

Comment: what do u mean by left side, please post the complete or part of the code that is not working.

Comment: Abhishek my Patient_Id is String value only. same code i am using with another hiddenfield and those are working fine.

Comment: Post the exact error message that you are getting there

Comment: System.NullReferenceException {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: Can you post your DOM as well? To see that how you have added that hidden field in your DOM.

Comment: Have you checked if the client submits the value to the server? (Use fiddler or something similar)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**
Your code

```
 select: function (event, ui) {
           $("#<%=hfPatientId.ClientID %>").val(ui.item.val);
        }
```

can't work, because you are try to select ASP element naming in jQuery, where are final HTML elements.

**Solution:**
Supposing ASP will produce that element as

```
 <input type="hidden" name="ClientID" id="ClientID" value="225">
```

so jQuery function you are seeking for is

```
 select: function (event, ui) {
           $("#ClientID").val(ui.item.val);
        }
```

If ID of that hidden element is not *ClientID*, change jQuery selector accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

thx everyone i found an problem...

i did some changes in my property..

before:-

```
  public string Patient_Id
    {
       get { return _patient_id; }
       set { _patient_id = Patient_ID; }
    }
```

Updated:-

```
  public string Patient_Id
   {
       get { return _patient_id; }
       set { _patient_id = value; }
   }
```

it's working fine now. Thanks again